# Ionic Mobile First Integration

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst

I developed Ionic Side Menu app and integrated IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1 using the below link.

https://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/03/23/working-with-ibm-mobilefirst-and-the-ionic-framework/

When I tried to build & run its throwing an error

> worklight.js:5383 Uncaught Exception: Uncaught Error:
>   [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ng due to:
>   TypeError: Cannot set property 'aHrefSanitizationWhitelist' of null
>       at $$SanitizeUriProvider

I googled and found the below Stack overflow link, but tried with using latest angular version still same issue.

- [AngularJS 1.5 error bootstrap IBM Mobilefirst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35774608/angularjs-1-5-error-bootstrap-ibm-mobilefirst)
- [Failed to instantiate module error in Angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20210269/failed-to-instantiate-module-error-in-angular-js)
- https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9692

IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1
Java SDK 1.8
IONIC version 1.7.14

app.js

```js
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
// 'starter.controllers' is found in controllers.js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
   /* if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }*/
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

    .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })

  .state('app.search', {
    url: '/search',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/search.html'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.browse', {
      url: '/browse',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/browse.html'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('app.playlists', {
      url: '/playlists',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/playlists.html',
          controller: 'PlaylistsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

  .state('app.single', {
    url: '/playlists/:playlistId',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/playlist.html',
        controller: 'PlaylistCtrl'
      }
    }
  });
  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/playlists');
});
```

```html
index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<!--     <script src="cordova.js"></script> -->
    <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
     <script src="js/wlinit.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show the `app.js` and `index.html`.

Comment: I edited the question, Please find it

Comment: I do not see reference to the `SanitizeUriProvider` in your code, you have the appropriate script in place and referenced in your app?

Comment: SanitizeUriProvider is in ionic.bundle.js

Comment: Have you added reference to `ng-sanitize` in your angular module?

Comment: I didnt add ngSanitize in angular module

Comment: I added ngSanitize in angular module, run and preview the app then still i am getting the same error

Comment: Nothing to do with ngSanitize - it's an incompatibility between MFP and Angular > 1.5.  Please don't downvote if you don't understand the issue!  See Idan's answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Update: MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1 now supports Angular 1.5; upgrade to the latest available iFix from IBM Fix Central.**

there is an incompatibility between Angular 1.5 and MFP 7.1.

To successfully make an Ionic app with MFP 7.1, an ionic version below 1.3 must be used (1.2.4 Copenhagen is the latest).

Ionic 1.3 introduced Angular 1.5

Comment: @MadhuMadhuri Have you tried it on the emulator/native rather than the preview?

Comment: I didnt try it in the emulator. I just run and  preview the App

Comment: @MadhuMadhuri  try with emulator also with my answered.if you failed let me know !

Comment: Idan - this is an issue with MFP 8.0's Cordova projects, too.  Not just MFP 7.1

Comment: Better open a PMR.

Comment: I've also pinged the dev team.

Comment: Is there an update concerning MFP 8 and Angular 1.5 ? @IdanAdar

Comment: There has not been a proper reproduction of the error in MFP 8. If you can proper a sample the shows the error it will be investigated.

Comment: @IdanAdar I have having this error with MFPv8 and angular js v1.5.3

Comment: @IdanAdar does this incopatibility exist between v1.5.3 and MFP 7.0?

Comment: @IdanAdar I tried and I get a similar error, that's why I am asking. Is there a fix for mobileFirst 7.0 as well?

Comment: Try the latest iFix from IBM Fix Central for 7.0; if it fails still you need to open a PMR.

Answer (score 0):

Since Angular seems to be the only variable that changes, this could potentially be an Angular issue instead.

I'd suggest trying the updated version of this

https://github.com/csantanapr/mfp-ionic-templates

Comment: As suggested I tried with ionic version 1.2.4 then i got localhost error and I also tried with ionic 1.3.22 then getting same error : worklight.js:5383 Uncaught Exception: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ng due to:
TypeError: Cannot set property 'aHrefSanitizationWhitelist' of null
    at $$SanitizeUriProvider