# AngularJS gives me injector Error in IBM MobileFirst

Tags: angularjs, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using AngularJS in IBM MobileFirst FrameWork and i am getting below error

> worklight.js:5359 Uncaught Exception: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=ng&p1=TypeError%3A%…Fpreview%2FAB%2Fcommon%2F0%2Fdefault%2Flibrary%2Fangular.min.js%3A39%3A321) at (compiled_code):40WL.Logger.__log @ worklight.js:5359PUBLIC_API.(anonymous function) @ worklight.js:5741WL.Logger.window.onerror @ worklight.js:5699
>   angular.min.js:6Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=ng&p1=TypeError%3A%…Fpreview%2FAB%2Fcommon%2F0%2Fdefault%2Flibrary%2Fangular.min.js%3A39%3A321)"

```
// ************ app.js *******************

var app = angular.module('myApp',['ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

    $stateProvider
        .state('login',{
            url:'/login',
            templateUrl:'view/login.html',
            controller:'loginController'
        });

});



// ******************  login.js ******************

app.controller('loginController',function($scope){});
```

```html
<!-- INDEX.HTML -->

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>AB</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
            <!--
                <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png"> 
            -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" />
            <script src="library/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="library/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="library/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
            <script src="library/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="controller/app.js"></script>
            <script src="controller/login.js"></script>
            <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
        </head>
        <body style="display: none;" ng-app="myApp">
            <!--application UI goes here-->

            <div ui-view id="view"></div>

            <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
            <script src="js/main.js"></script>
            <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
        </body>
</html>
```

```
<div ng-controller="loginController" class="container-fluid">
Login Page
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular 1.5 is incompatible, see here: [Ionic Mobile First Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37318540/ionic-mobile-first-integration)

You may need to download an older release.

Comment: I am using angular1.4.9 and now its working fine for me